# Which values of the exponent yield only real values of this function on the given domain

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function, radial-basis-functions

Given the following function:
$$
y = \frac{x^p}{x^p + (1 - x)^p},
$$
where $x,p\in\mathbb{R}$, I want to know which values of $p$ yields $y\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $x$. Can anyone help me with this?

Please see [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ospn9of8ay) link for a Desmos graph of $y$ with a slider for $p$.

Comment: If you allow $x^{1/3}$ on the negative reals, the answer is different than if $x^{1/3}$ which has the positive reals as its domain. Which do you mean?

Comment: @robjohn I agree, but I'm not sure how that relates here? Can you elaborate?

Comment: if $x^{1/3}$ is real for $x\lt0$, then you can use all $x$. If $x^{1/3}$ is complex, then you can't use all $x$. It seems to affect the answer. There is nothing you can really do with $x^{.333}$.

Comment: @robjohn Okay, I understand. But maybe I'm not sure how to phrase my question correctly then. If you check out the desmos graph I've linked to in my post, there are some values of $p$ that restrict the graph to the domain $[0, 1]$ and other values of $p$ that do not impose this restriction. Perhaps I misguidedly assumed that the latter case arose only when the output $y$ was real on $\mathbb{R}\setminus[0, 1]$. So what I actually mean to ask is under what conditions of $p$ is the domain of the function not restricted to $[0, 1]$? I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Yes, and that is due to $x^p$ being real/complex for negative $x$. fractional $p$ present problems when defining $x^p$. Often one defines $x^p=e^{p\log(x)}$, but when $x\lt0$, we have to delve into complex logarithms, of which there are an infinitude; this means we need to pick out which complex log we are using. For example, $(-1)^{1/3}$ can be $-1$, $\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2$, or $\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2$ depending on the branch of log used. Non-rational exponents can present an infinitude of possibilities.

Comment: What Desmos is doing is finding the lowest term rational number for the exponent. for example, $1.4$ goes beyond $[0,1]$ because that exponent can be represented by $\frac75$ and $x^5=-1$ has a real solution $x=-1$. However, it uses $\frac32$ for $1.5$ and there is no real solution for $x^2=-1$, so it restricts the graph to $[0,1]$. This is all dependent on the branch of log used to define $x^p$. Desmos is using different branches depending on the lowest term rational representation for the exponent.

Comment: @robjohn Okay, I see. I have very informal knowledge of complex analysis, so I'm vaguely familiar with your reference to 'branch cuts'. Will read about them further. Thanks for the insights :)

Comment: Try out $\frac53$ and $\frac75$ as exponents; they extend outside $[0,1]$. Try out $\frac54$ and $\frac76$; they will be limited to $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desmos seems to be using a rational approximation, $\frac ab$ where $(a,b)=1$, for the exponent, $p$. If $b$ is odd, the plot will extend to all $\mathbb{R}$. If $b$ is even, the plot will be restricted to $[0,1]$.

Desmos seems to be computing $(-1)^{a/b}=\left((-1)^{1/b}\right)^a$. When $b$ is odd, $x^b=-1$ has the real solution $x=-1$. However, when $b$ is even, $x^b=-1$ does not have a real solution.